# Connecting my IOS App to an existing PHP application

Tags: php, mysql, ios, mobile

I am interested in creating an IOS application that leverages an existing PHP/MySQL application.

Currently, my application is web based.  I would like to enable a mobile version of the tool without recreating the logic I have already implemented in PHP.  Basically, I would like to keep my IOS app thin and use some form of RPC to interact with my PHP code.

I was thinking about doing something custom by creating a query/response system using XML.  However, I am afraid that I am recreating the wheel.  Any suggestions about the best way to do this?

Comment: Use JSON instead of XML, since IOS 5 apple has made it easy to work with

Comment: Why dont you create an api using ur existing app in PHP and query the api from the mobile app? This way you would have exact control over what you want to expose externally

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP in cooperation with JSON makes it very easy to communicate between PHP and iOS.

On the server, arrays can be formatted to JSON as follows:

**Server Example**

```
<?php
$response = cydia_check("eswick", $_GET['package'], $_GET['version'], $_GET['udid'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], "local", $apikey);//Example function, returns an array. (In this case, checks an activation server to verify if the app was really purchased.)

print json_encode($response);//Prints JSON encoding of array to stdout.
?>
```

As of iOS 5, thanks to Twitter, Foundation includes a class that makes it simple to parse JSON. Here is some example code that calls and parses the PHP function above:

**Client Example**

```
#define PACKAGE "com.eswick.drmtest"
#define VERSION "0.8"

NSString *requestAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.eswick.com/check.php?package=%@&version=%@&udid=%@", PACKAGE, VERSION, MGCopyAnswer(kMGUniqueDeviceID)];

NSMutableURLRequest *request =[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestAddress]];



NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSHTTPURLResponse *responseCode = nil;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&responseCode error:&error];//Get the output of the PHP page we loaded.

if(!responseData)
    return false;

NSError *parseError = nil;
id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&parseError];//Parse the JSON output from responseData.

if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){//Make sure the output is an array.
    NSString *state = [result valueForKey:@"state"];//Check the array returned by PHP for a value named 'state'.

    if (!state){//If it doesn't exist, fail.
        return false;
    }else{
        if([state isEqualToString:@"purchased"])//If app is truly purchased, return success.
            return true;
    }

}
```

This should give you a general idea of how this would work. You will have to change it to fit your needs, but this is a very basic concept.

Obviously, don't *actually* use this *example* code as a DRM.

Comment: Glad I could help! Remember, if this solved your problem, please mark it as the answer (and preferably upvote it :D). It helps with the answerer's reputation!

Answer (score 0):

I think below link can solve your question.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app